# Core Java on division by 0.0

Tags: java, string, arithmeticexception

I heard one twist in java. If anyone know proper reason you're asked to share it.
Question is:

```
double result1 = 1.0/0.0;
sop(result1); // output Infinity
double result2 = 0.0/0.0;
sop(result2); // output NaN
```

the same is happening for `float` variable also. but for int type its raising `ArithmeticException`. Why?

Note: I am using jdk 1.7

Comment: Because neither `Infinity` nor `NaN` cannot be represented with integer encoding

Comment: @Ortis and _shouldn't_, because they are not integers.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot represent infinity or NAN using an int.

From [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.2)

> The result of a floating-point division is determined by the rules of
>   IEEE 754 arithmetic:
>
> Division of a nonzero finite value by a zero results in a signed
>   infinity. The sign is determined by the rule stated above.

Check the [IEEE explanation](http://grouper.ieee.org/groups/754/faq.html#exceptions)

> **Why doesn't division by zero (or overflow, or underflow) stop the
>   program or trigger an error? Why does a standard on numbers include
>   "not-a-number" (NaN)?** The 754 model encourages robust programs. It is
>   intended not only for numerical analysts but also for spreadsheet
>   users, database systems, or even coffee pots. The propagation rules
>   for NaNs and infinities allow inconsequential exceptions to vanish.
>   Similarly, gradual underflow maintains error properties over a
>   precision's range.
>
> When exceptional situations need attention, they can be examined
>   immediately via traps or at a convenient time via status flags. Traps
>   can be used to stop a program, but unrecoverable situations are
>   extremely rare. Simply stopping a program is not an option for
>   embedded systems or network agents. More often, traps log diagnostic
>   information or substitute valid results.
>
> Flags offer both predictable control flow and speed. Their use
>   requires the programmer be aware of exceptional conditions, but flag
>   stickiness allows programmers to delay handling exceptional conditions
>   until necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Infinity or undefined numbers are not a part of the integer set, so they are excluded from `int` and `Integer`. This is the same in most programming languages, not in `Java` per se.

But the real reason is historical, of course. Integers used to be represented using 2-complement binary logic. It was not in the standards that there was a `NaN` or `Infinity`.